# How to creat the nested Grid on the specfic Grid in WPF C# application

Tags: wpf, nested, grid, orientation

In my WPF application, I have to place label(Baudrate And ComboBoxOfBaudrate, DataBits And ComboBoxOfDataBits, parityBits And ComboBoxOfParityBits , StopBit And ComboBoxof StopBits) and the combo box on the same grid so when I enlarge the window they can be displayed with out any alteration on its view.
I intend to use nested Grid inside the specific grids which I need to divide for Label and combo box.

```
<Window
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SerialReadAndWrite"
        xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" x:Class="ATR220ReadAndWrite.MainWindow"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="ATR220ReadAndWrite" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition Height="0.75*"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ComboBox x:Name="ComPortComboBox"  Width="98" Height=" 17" SelectionChanged="ComPort_SelectionChanged" DropDownOpened="ComPort_DropDownOpened"  IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="False" FontSize="10" FontFamily="Arial" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
        <Label Content="PortNumber :" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="12"/>
        <Label Content="PortSettings :" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Center"  FontSize="12" FontFamily="Arial"/>
        <Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="26" Margin="359,14,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="29" RenderTransformOrigin="-0.23,0.36"/>
        <ComboBox x:Name="BaudRateComboBox" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="98" Height="17" SelectionChanged="BaudRate_SelectionChanged"  IsEnabled="False" IsReadOnly="True" FontSize="10" FontFamily="Arial" >
            <System:String>115200</System:String>
            <System:String>57600</System:String>
            <System:String>38400</System:String>
            <System:String>19200</System:String>
            <System:String>14400</System:String>
            <System:String>9600</System:String>
            <System:String>4800</System:String>
        </ComboBox>
        <ComboBox x:Name="ParityComboBox" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="17" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="4" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="98" SelectionChanged="Parity_SelectionChanged"  IsEnabled="False" FontSize="10" FontFamily="Arial">
            <System:String>Even</System:String>
            <System:String>Mark</System:String>
            <System:String>None</System:String>
            <System:String>Odd</System:String>
            <System:String>Space</System:String>
        </ComboBox>
        <ComboBox x:Name="DataBitsComboBox" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="17" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="98" SelectionChanged="DataBits_SelectionChanged"  IsEnabled="False" FontSize="10" FontFamily="Arial">
            <System:String>5</System:String>
            <System:String>6</System:String>
            <System:String>7</System:String>
            <System:String>8</System:String>
        </ComboBox>
        <ComboBox x:Name="StopBitsComboBox" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="17" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="4" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="98" SelectionChanged="StopBits_SelectionChanged" IsEnabled="False" FontSize="10" FontFamily="Arial">
            <System:String>One</System:String>
            <System:String>Two</System:String>
            <System:String>OnePointFive</System:String>
        </ComboBox>
        <Label Content="Baudrate"  Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center"  VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" FontSize="12" FontStyle="Italic" Width="62"/>
        <Label Content="Parity" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3"  VerticalAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" FontSize="12" FontStyle="Italic" Width="62" />
        <Label Content="DataBits" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" FontSize="12" FontStyle="Italic" Width="62" />
        <Label Content="StopBit" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="3" VerticalAlignment="Center"  VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" FontSize="12" FontStyle="Italic" Width="62" />
        <Button x:Name="ConnectButton" Content="Connect" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="5" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="75" Click="ConnectButton_Click" IsEnabled="False" Height="17" FontSize="10" FontFamily="Arial"/>
        <Label Content="ProtocolType: " HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="5" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="12" FontFamily="Arial" />
        <ComboBox x:Name="ProtocolTypeComboBox"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="17" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="5" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="98" SelectionChanged="ProtocolTypeComboBox_SelectionChanged" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" IsReadOnly="True" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" FontSize="10" FontFamily="Arial" IsEnabled="False">
            <System:String>WLink</System:String>
        </ComboBox>
        <StatusBar HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="28" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="794">
            <StatusBarItem FontSize="9" FontFamily="Arial" TextOptions.TextHintingMode="Fixed">
                <TextBlock Name= "PortStatus"/>
            </StatusBarItem>
        </StatusBar>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Also I have created the statusBar for displaying some data , But I do not see the status Bar at all.

So please some one guide me to do this orientation as I have little knowledge of WPF.

Please see the image of enlarge window  as the labels and ComBoBoxes are well separated which I do not like it.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VpsDo.png)

Comment: If i understand the issue Correctly, you should only need to add size restrictions to the main Grid for your labels and combo boxes. Something like `<Grid Width="400", Height="500">`
You could also set a numeric value for your `RowDefinition`s and/or `ColumnDefinition`s. But this would be a little more frustrating to maintain.

Comment: The status bar is not visible maybe because you have not specified the `Grid.Row` and `Grid.Column` properties and its getting hidden by other controls. For the proper alignment of your control you need to provide Height to the `RowDefinitions` and Width to the `ColumnDefinitions`